# Updating Heroku Review App Environment/Config Vars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, configuration

I am working on a legacy Rails project that uses Heroku's review apps feature. When review apps automatically deploy, RAILS_ENV is being set to 'review'.  This value is not specified in the app.json and RAILS_ENV is set to 'production' in the staging environment.  Where could I look to make sure that this environment variable is being copied from the parent app?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my issue by examining the app.json file.  There was a postdeploy script running a custom rake task updating the config_vars.

More broadly, config vars are set by the settings in app.json file's env attribute along with any updates in the specified postdeploy script.  If you want to get a little formatting help, you can access an app.json generator in the heroku UI by heading to `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your-app-name/app-json`